# If statements with json data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out how to run an if statement with this as the returned JSON data. When there is an error I want it to find out if its the username or password input that has the error and append a label with a class of error the actual error. So the if statement below needs to find out if its the data error is a username or not and then place in the error instead of error.

```
{"output_status":"Error","output_title":"Form Not Validated","output_message":"The form did not validate successfully!","error_messages":{"username":"This is not have an accepted value!"}}

if (data.output_status == 'Error') 
{

    if (data.?)
    {        
        $('#username').after('<label class="error">error</label>');
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I"m not sure what is going on but now I'm getting a notice the the form didn't get submitted for some reason.

```
$('#login_form :input:visible').each(function() {
var name = $(this).attr('name');
if (data.error_messages.name)
    {
        $(this).after('<label class="error">' + data.error_messages.name + '</label>');
    }
});

public function submit()
{
    $output_status = 'Notice';
    $output_title = 'Not Processed';
    $output_message = 'The request was unprocessed!';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_username');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember Me', 'trim|xss_clean|integer');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $output_status = 'Error';
        $output_title = 'Form Not Validated';
        $output_message = 'The form did not validate successfully!';
    }

    echo json_encode(array('output_status' => $output_status, 'output_title' => $output_title, 'output_message' => $output_message, 'error_messages' => $this->form_validation->error_array()));
}

public function check_username($str)
{
    if (preg_match('#[a-z0-9]#', $str)) 
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'This is not have an accepted value!');
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (data.error_messages['username'])
{        
    $('#username').after('<label class="error">' + data.error_messages['username'] + '</label>');
}
```

Now as a bonus, you can iterate over all your input fields and do the same:

```
$('#form-id :input:visible').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (data.error_messages[id])
    {        
        $(this).after('<label class="error">' + data.error_messages[id] + '</label>');
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I get the value of what that error message is to put in instead of "error".

Comment: `$('#username').after('<label class="error">' + data.error_messages['username']) + '</label>');`

Comment: FYI: I'd use the input's `name` attribute instead of the `id` because that is what gets sent to the server. Just my 0.02c

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with php... What language are those two functions in? CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the error message by the object key - in this case "username":

```
 if(data.error_messages["username"]) // this return undefined if it doesn't exist
 {
   // code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (data.output_status == 'Error') 
{

    if (data.error_messages.username)
    {        
        $('#username').after('<label class="error">' + data.error_messages.username + '</label>');
    }
}
```

If there is no username error, `data.error_messages.username` will just return undefined.

Comment: How would I get the value of what that error message is to put in instead of "error".